# Segmentation fault in sorting algorithm

Tags: c++

so when I run the following code in Xcode, it works, but gives segmentation fault when I run it in terminal and I'm not sure why.

```
void Word::arrangeWords(char **&words, int*& pages, int size)
{

char *lowest;
int track;
{
    for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        lowest=new char[30];
        strcpy(lowest, words[i]);;
        for(int j=i+1;j<size;j++)
        {
            int compResult=strcmp(lowest, words[j]);
            if (compResult>0)
            {
                strcpy(lowest, words[j]);
                track=j;
            }
        }
        std::swap(words[track],words[i]);
        std::swap(pages[track],pages[i]);
        delete [] lowest;
    }
}

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well have you checked the obvious first? Verify that all the words are less than 29 characters long (not including null terminator) and that the words and pages arrays are at least as large as size.

Comment: No word in words will ever be greater than 30 characters.  the arrays are also as large as size so that shouldn't be a problem

Comment: @Anonymous the word has to be *less than 30* characters. In any case it wouldn't hurt to add a check.  And passing `words` by reference is dangerous, make the function take `char **words` and `int *pages`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't figure out what's causing the segmentation fault but there is a bug in your code. You are not resetting the value of `track` after the calls to `std::swap`. I suggest the following changes to the function.

```
void Word::arrangeWords(char **&words, int*& pages, int size)
{
   for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
   {
      int track = i;
      char lowest[30]; // If you know the size of the array to be 30,
                       // just create an array. Why use new char[30]?
      strcpy(lowest, words[i]);;
      for(int j=i+1;j<size;j++)
      {
         int compResult=strcmp(lowest, words[j]);
         if (compResult>0)
         {
            strcpy(lowest, words[j]);
            track=j;
         }
      }
      if ( track > i )
      {
         std::swap(words[track],words[i]);
         std::swap(pages[track],pages[i]);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't know how, but this solution fixed the segmentation error. thanks

Comment: In the original code, track was always used but not always set to any value, so words[track] might not be ok.